# How does software interact with the cpu in the fetch execute cycle?

Tags: memory-hardware

As the question suggests, is there any interaction or relationships between any sort of software and the cpu during the fetch-execute cycle?

Comment: The common model for the CPU is it interacts with ports and controllers, ROM, RAM, input devices, output devices, secondary storages through Bus. Software is out of the picture or discussion in general. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you.